# Netsuite getAttribute throws an error

Tags: javascript, netsuite, getattribute

What I am trying to accomplish is to get item information from the internal ID passed to getAttribute but I am getting the following error.

```
Error processing dynamic tag getAttribute('item',362,'storedisplayname') : id paramter 2 must be an integer
```

Here is a sample of the code:

```
var itemIntId = 362;
var id = "<%=getAttribute('item',"+itemIntId+",'storedisplayname')%>";
console.log("ID: " + id);
```

Doing the following does not seem to change anything as it still gives me the same error

```
var id = "<%=declareAttribute('item',"+itemIntId+",'storedisplayname')%>";
console.log("ID: " + id);
```

This is in a presentation tab page and found the following info in the Netsuite help section

> getAttribute tag on Presentation tab throws error Sometimes using the
>   getAttribute() tag in a Presentation tab can throw error %u2018Error
>   processing dynamic tag getAttribute('item',9047,'storeurl') %u2018. In
>   that case you have to use declareAttribute() to display the embedded
>   tag on your Presentation tab. On the Presentation tab > Meta Tag HTML
>   area, just add:

```
<%=declareAttribute('item',9047,'storeurl')%>
```

but did not seem to help

I'm sure I am just missing something simple but have been bashing my head against my desk for a few hours now trying to figure this out and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after talking with Netsuite support and going back and forth on the code it seems that the getAttribute or declareAttribute can not take a dynamic variable from JavaScript. Not sure why as its still an int but I guess it is what it is.